# Determine unknown lengths of triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a similar triangles question which I am stuck on. What is known is the angle $\theta$ and the length $y$ (values don't really matter). While the lengths $\alpha$, $\beta$, $t$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ and $x$ are all unknowns. Through trigonometry, I was able to obtain values for $\gamma$+$\delta$ and $t$+$\beta$. What I want to know is if there is a way to determine the value of $t$ or are there simply too many unknowns to do so. Any help is appreciated. Feel free to edit my question for clarity. Sorry for my hand writing but $\gamma$ is the length at the top of the triangle, $y$ is the longest length

[image]

Comment: If you want that rectangle to be a square (for instance) then you have enough to solve.

Comment: @Arthur Good point. That's OP's to clarify, but as-is the sides are labeled $\,x\,$ and $\,\beta\,$, so not necessarily equal though the drawing could certainly suggest that.

Comment: Thanks for help, I suspected that there were too many unknowns but was hopping I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that, with fixed $\,y, \theta\,$ and moving the point defined by $\,\alpha\,$ along the hypotenuse:

- for $\,\alpha \to 0\,$: $\;t\to y \cos(\theta)\,$
- for $\,\alpha \to y\,$: $\;t \to 0\,$

There is simply not enough information to solve the figure for $\,t\,$, since each $\,0 \le \alpha \le y\,$ would give a different $\,t = (y - \alpha) \cos(\theta)\,$.